# Docker swarm connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm, consul, seneca

I am using seneca.js as microservices framework. Evrything works fine in local but when I deply services to swarm I have problem with messages ping service is somhow blocked, here is error from my api gateway when run route:

> {"statusCode":502,"error":"Bad Gateway","message":"connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 10.100.0.5:55010"}

Here is my setup:

```
docker network create -d overlay --subnet 10.100.0.0/16 test-net

docker service create --network test-net -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:53/udp --name node1 progrium/consul -server -bootstrap -ui-dir /ui

docker service create --network test-net --name bases -e HOST=bases -e REGISTRY=node1 vforv/bases:v2

docker service create --network test-net -p 5000:5000 --name api -e BASES=bases -e HOST=api -e REGISTRY=node1 vforv/api-gateway:v2

docker service create --network test-net --name ping -e HOST=ping -e REGISTRY=node1 vforv/ping-service:v3
```

here is code:

https://github.com/vforv/hapi-seneca-ts

Anyone know what is problem?